# multiline textbox

Tags: asp.net

my problem if the user enter one sentence/word in mulitiline textbox and press enter button
then that word which is pressed befor enter buuton should be stored in database.
means if user enters in one textarea in format
1 GB
2 GB
3 GB
80 GB
as filter options then in database these should be stored as different rows.
hope you understood my problem.

Comment: Homework? Show us your code please.

Answer (score 1):

So your user enters:

```
1GB
2GB
3GB
80GB
```

and you want to split those out so you can save them as four separate records in your database?

Using the `Split` function on a string allows you to carve up a string into an array based on a string separator. In your case we'd use a newline character to split the original textbox string:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textLines;
        string[] textLine;

        textLines=MultilineTextBox.Text;

        textLine = textLines.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(),  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // At this point the textLines array will have four entries in it, one for each line in the textbox on the form
    }
```

You can then loop through the array to save the rows into your database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest better to use a combination of a textbox Singleline and a Listbox. But if you want a Multiline textbox(and without Ajax) have a look:

```
function checkEnter(e){ 
        var characterCode
        if(e && e.which){ 
            e = e
            characterCode = e.which 
        } else {
            e = event
            characterCode = e.keyCode
        }
        if(characterCode == 13){ 
            var txt=document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientId%>');
            txt.blur(); 
        }
    }

    function moveCursorToEndOfTextBox(){
        var txt=document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientId%>');
        txt.focus();
        txt.value = txt.value+'\n';
    }


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onkeypress="checkEnter(this)" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextChanged" TextMode="MultiLine"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal evt As EventArgs)
    Dim allLines As New List(Of String)(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split(Me.TextBox1.Text.Trim, vbCrLf))
    Dim newLine As String = allLines(allLines.Count - 1)
    'save new item to db .....

    'register script to jump into textbox and got to end of text
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "moveCursorToEndOfTextBox", "moveCursorToEndOfTextBox();", True)
    End Sub
```